# .httaccess mod_rewrite by first hiding the .php extension and then query string variable

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

This might be a duplicate, but I am having difficulties in finding a proper solution to solve my problem.
I would like to accomplish the following:

**STEP 1:** Hide PHP extension for all my pages. And **I managed to do that** by having:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

**STEP 2:** Hide query string, meaning variables passed from another page. And this is the part I am missing.

From **index** I pass the following link:

```
setup?id=123
```

In my **setup** page, I do the **$_GET['id']** to read the id attribute.

URL shows it as

```
http://subdomain.localhost:777/setup?id=123
```

So, everything works as expected.

My question now is how do I rework my httaccess so that it hides the **?id=123** part and shows it as:

```
http://subdomain.localhost:777/setup
```

Any help or guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: [Rewrite rules don't make ugly URLs pretty, they make pretty URLs ugly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67254596/157957). If the pretty URL doesn't have "123" in it anywhere, there's no way to magically add it to the resulting ugly URL.

Comment: I think that you won't get $_GET['id'] anymore after such rewrite. Only solution is to save it in a session and then redirect to url without get parameters by php.

Comment: Thanks a lot @IMSoP and @Robert! I think I got it now. :-)